# Invalid Number with Substitution Variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am having trouble trying to get an input to be accepted as a number variable. Here is the code I have:

```
ACCEPT clientidnum NUMBER PROMPT 'Enter Client Number(s): '

SELECT * FROM PROD.GS_EXTERNAL_CONTACT@prd1.WORLD 
WHERE GEC_GS_EXT_CONTACT_ID IN (SELECT GEC_GS_EXT_CONTACT_ID
                      FROM PROD.CLIENT@prd1.WORLD a
                      WHERE CT_CLIENT_ID = to_number(trim(replace('&clientidnum',CHR(13)))) AND
                a.GEC_GS_EXT_CONTACT_ID NOT IN (SELECT GEC_GS_EXT_CONTACT_ID 
                                FROM PROD.GS_EXTERNAL_CONTACT b
                                WHERE a.GEC_GS_EXT_CONTACT_ID= b.GEC_GS_EXT_CONTACT_ID));
```

And when I run this in SQL Plus, it comes back with the below error:

```
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Thanks for the assistance! Sorry if this is an easy question, but I'm use to SQL Server and was thrown on Oracle to get some things to work correctly.

Comment: when you prompt for number, you should reference the variable without apostrophes, simply with `WHERE CT_CLIENT_ID = &clientidnum`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Pavel, however I still receive the same error message when I do that.

Comment: what is your input? make `PROMPT &clientidnum` after `ACCEPT`

Comment: 40310 is the number I am using as a test. This number returns results if I just run the `SELECT` statement with it in.
I moved the `PROMPT` to the next line so now it looks like this:
`ACCEPT clientidnum NUMBER`
`PROMPT 'Enter Client Number(s): '`

However that won't even allow me to enter the input now.

Comment: Change `to_number(trim(replace('&clientidnum',CHR(13))))` to `&clientidnum`.  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm.  When I use your example with `dual`, I do not receive an error.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but already tried that and still receiving same error message. New code:
`SELECT * FROM PROD.GS_EXTERNAL_CONTACT@prd1.WORLD 
WHERE GEC_GS_EXT_CONTACT_ID IN (SELECT GEC_GS_EXT_CONTACT_ID
FROM PROD.CLIENT@prd1.WORLD a
WHERE CT_CLIENT_ID = &clientidnum
AND a.GEC_GS_EXT_CONTACT_ID NOT IN (SELECT GEC_GS_EXT_CONTACT_ID 
FROM PROD.GS_EXTERNAL_CONTACT b 
WHERE a.GEC_GS_EXT_CONTACT_ID= b.GEC_GS_EXT_CONTACT_ID));`

I should add I am running this in SQL Plus and not SQL Developer, if that helps

Comment: it seems the column CT_CLIENT_ID has not a numeric data type

Comment: Are you truly trying to accept a csv list of clientid numbers?  Certainly if you are testing this, you have nothing to convert a csv substitution variable to a list of numbers (a ` , ` between numbers could result in ORA-01722).  This is a little more complicated, yet you will find many examples of how to do that here.

Comment: The column is numeric data type as I checked that on the table before just in case. 
I am not accepting a csv list, but a simple input at the SQL Plus prompt. Sorry if this is confusing, I'm trying to be as detailed as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. `SET DEFINE` was set to `OFF` in my glogin.sql script. I added `SET DEFINE ON` to the script I am running and it works.